# How to use Session::Run (TensorFlow C++ API) to perform CNN based classification of samples in batch mode

Tags: c++, tensorflow, deep-learning

I would like to perform a classification of multiple samples using a pretrained CNN in C++ in a batch mode. So far:

- I have trained a CNN model with Keras in Python and transformed this model using the small script provided by the is repo (https://github.com/amir-abdi/keras_to_tensorflow).
- and I was able to load the model using the `ReadBinaryProto` function and created a `Session` object.

Now I would like to perform classification of `n` input tensors. The following code works but is quite slow since one run with (~20msec) is quite fast but has to be performed about 20.000 times.

```
std::vector<tensorflow::Tensor> outputs;
std::vector<tensorflow::Tensor> tensor(tensorflow::DT_FLOAT,
     tensorflow::TensorShape({1, winSize, winSize, nochannels }));;
for (unsigned int n = 0; n < noSamples; n++)
{
    copyDataToTensor(prevImg, prevPoints[n], input_tensor, 0);
    tensorflow::Status run_status = m_Session->Run({ { "conv2d_5_input", tensor} }, { "output_node0" }, {}, &outputs);
    ... evaluate outputs ...
}
```

`winSize` and `noChannels` are some constant that are related to then CNN input shape.

What I am looking for is a approach to run multiple samples in a batch mode like:

```
 std::vector<tensorflow::Tensor> outputs;
 std::vector<tensorflow::Tensor> tensor(tensorflow::DT_FLOAT, 
      tensorflow::TensorShape({noSamples, winSize, winSize, nochannels }));;
 for (unsigned int n = 0; n < noSamples; n++)
 {
    copyDataToTensor(prevImg, prevPoints[n], input_tensor, n);
 }
 tensorflow::Status run_status = m_Session->Run({ { "conv2d_5_input", tensor} }, { "output_node0" }, {}, &outputs);
 ... evaluate outputs ...
```

However, this approach is not working since `outputs` has one element only and the content for this tensor stores the results of only one classification results.

Providing an `output_tensor_names` vectors with `noSamples` times  `{"ouput_node0"}` is not working as well. Then `outputs` tensor vector has the correct size but each tensor is similar.

How could I use this function correct to perform the prediction in a batch mode? Is there another interface I have to use for that issue?

Answer (score 1):

It seamed that reason for the strange behaviour of the second batch mode was a bug in the Keras to Python tranfor script from this repo (https://github.com/amir-abdi/keras_to_tensorflow) is used.

A small bug which lead to a wrong results as it connected the output in a wrong manner and not to the dense_2/Softmax node. The buggy code was:

K.set_learning_phase(0)
net_model = load_model(weight_file_path)

```
pred = [None]*num_output
pred_node_names = [None]*num_output
for i in range(num_output):
     pred_node_names[i] = prefix_output_node_names_of_final_network+str(i)
     pred[i] = tf.identity(net_model.output[i], name=pred_node_names[i]),
print('output nodes names are: ', pred_node_names)
sess = K.get_session()
constant_graph = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(sess, sess.graph.as_graph_def(), pred_node_names)
graph_io.write_graph(constant_graph, output_fld, output_graph_name, as_text=False)
```

It seams that there was a small typo in net_model.output[i]. If the outputs field had been used instead (net_model.outputs[i]) everythink works fine. I. e. the fix will be:

```
K.set_learning_phase(0)
net_model = load_model(weight_file_path)

pred = [None]*num_output
pred_node_names = [None]*num_output
for i in range(num_output):
     pred_node_names[i] = prefix_output_node_names_of_final_network+str(i)
     pred[i] = tf.identity(net_model.outputs[i], name=pred_node_names[i]),
print('output nodes names are: ', pred_node_names)
sess = K.get_session()
constant_graph = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(sess, sess.graph.as_graph_def(), pred_node_names)
graph_io.write_graph(constant_graph, output_fld, output_graph_name, as_text=False)
```

Comment: This 'output' bug has caused me lots of trouble as well. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51967552/convert-keras-h5-to-tensorflow-pb-for-batch-inference